# How to access file with unacceptable file name

Tags: filenames, delete-file

I don't know is this site a good place to ask this question... A long time ago, my operating system was linux. On linux I made a file with name `\/:*?"<>|`. Then I installed windows instead of linux, but now I cannot access or delete this file. I tried to delete it using Unlocker, ProceXP, Command Prompt and many other programs, but I couldn't. Also, I tried all commands in Command Prompt which can be used for deleting undeletable files, but this file is still here. If I try to rename it, process `explorer.exe` crashes. Then I installed linux again and this file become accessable.
Now I have windows and another file with name `\/:*?"<>|`. Is it possible to access this file without installing linux? Is there a way to access place on filesystem where this file name is stored and manualy change it to any acceptable file name? If yes, can you explain which program is best for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using DeleteDoctor. I've used it under similar situations as yours with great success. You can download a copy here:

```
http://www.download25.com/delete-doctor-download.html
```

Comment: I tried this software and it says "The file cannot be deleted using this method." My question is how to access this file, not delete. Is it possible to manualy change the name of this file? Where are the file names stored on the filesystem?